# Execute Function Every X Seconds On Class Init

Tags: python, multithreading

I have created a [jabberbot](http://thp.io/2007/python-jabberbot/) class that I would like to broadcast scheduled messages. I don't have much experience with threads (in any language) but I am having an especially hard time grasping the concept with python.

My lattest attempt was using [threading.timer](http://docs.python.org/library/threading.html#timer-objects) something like this:

```
class myBot(JabberBot):
     def __init__( self, jid, password, res = none):
         autoNotify()

      def autoNotify():
           #Send timed message
           self.send('someuser@jabber.example.com','cooool message text!')
           #set/reset timer
           t = Timer(05,self.autoNotify)
           t.start()
```

The problem with this is that it continuously spawns new threads until it eventually dies.  I've read numerous examples on SO using third party libraries, messaging queues, and twisted, but my question is simply this - Is there really no easy way to spawn a single asynchronous thread?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Yes, there is](http://docs.python.org/library/threading.html#thread-objects).

However, you should really not spawn a thread in a constructor. Instead, provide a `run` method and inherit from `threading.Thread`, this will make a public `start` method available that can be used to start the notification loop. Something like this:

```
import threading
import time

class myBot(JabberBot, threading.Thread):
  def __init__( self, jid, password, res = none):
    threading.Thread.__init__(self)

  def run(self):
    while True:
      self.autoNotify()
      time.sleep(5) # wait 4 seconds

  def autoNotify(self):
    self.send('someuser@jabber.example.com','cooool message text!')
```

Use like this:

```
 myBot(...).start()
```

If you can't or don't want to use multiple inheritance for some reason, you can also do something like this:

```
class myBot(JabberBot):
  def start(self):
    threading.Thread(target=self.autoNotifyLoop).start()

  def autoNotifyLoop(self):
    while True:
      self.autoNotify()
      time.sleep(5) # wait 4 seconds

  def autoNotify(self):
    self.send('someuser@jabber.example.com','cooool message text!')
```

You can also create a function for that, for maximum "convenience":

```
def call_async(func, *args, **kw):
  threading.Thread(target=func, args=args, kwargs=kw).start()

def do_something(msg):
  print msg

call_async(do_something, "Don't overuse threads!")
```

Comment: Awesome examples, thanks a ton! Any chance you could expand on why you shouldn't spawn a thread in a constructor? I think I understand why already, but Id love to know from someone who knows better than I.

Comment: @HurnsMobile: It's a simple rule: Don't ever do anything in a constructor apart from initialization. Users of your API don't expect constructors to have side-effects, so don't do it. It has and will lead to subtle bugs that are hard to track down.